# Compare List of objects in java script

Tags: javascript, list, performance, search, big-o

I want to create a function to compare a list of objects in the fast way

```
for (let i = 0; i < posts.length - 1; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < posts.length; j++) {
    const post1 = posts[i];
    const post2 = posts[j];

    if (validation(post1, post2)){
      console.log(`found comparation`);
    }
  }
}
```

And the validation function compares two fields like this:

```
const validation = (post1, post2) => post1.need.includes(post2.have) &&
    post2.need.includes(post1.have);
```

What would be the fastest way to perform this search? These 'need' and 'have' strings are IDs for a category where I associate them by levels like '01030204'. In case it's useful to know, I'm open to dividing the data based on this, but I'm really looking for ideas on how to improve the speed of this search.

Comment: do you have a small set of data and wanted result?

Comment: Instead of `need` being arrays, define them as sets. Then you can use the `has` method instead of `includes`.

Comment: Please confirm if "need" and "have" are string or arrays or what.  Give us some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`includes` is not an efficient method when you have to repeat it on the same array several times. Also, if you would key your data by those `have` strings, and register for each of them which are the `need` strings that can be reached by which posts, then you have a more efficient adjacency list (graph data structure), and can hope to find such matching pairs faster.

As you didn't provide sample data, I had to invent some. Here is a possible implementation:

```js
// Sample data
const posts = [
    { id: 1, have: "a", need: ["b", "c", "d"] },
    { id: 2, have: "a", need: ["b", "e"] },
    { id: 3, have: "b", need: ["c"] },
    { id: 4, have: "c", need: [] },
    { id: 5, have: "d", need: ["a", "c"] },
    { id: 6, have: "d", need: ["a"] },
    { id: 7, have: "e", need: ["b", "d"] },
];

// Create a 2-level dictionary to register "edges" from "have" to "need"
// identifying which posts establish each edge.
const map = {};
for (const post of posts) {
    const needs = (map[post.have] ??= {});
    for (const need of post.need) {
        (needs[need] ??= []).push(post);
    }
}

// Iterate the 2-level dictionary to find matching pairs:
for (const [start, startMap] of Object.entries(map)) {
    for (const [end, posts] of Object.entries(startMap)) {
        if (end < start) continue;
        const backPosts = map[end]?.[start]; // This has the opposite directed edges
        if (!backPosts) continue;
        for (const post1 of posts) {
            for (const post2 of backPosts) {
                console.log(`Found mutually related posts via "need" ${end}:`);
                console.log(`  ${JSON.stringify(post1)}`);
                console.log(`  ${JSON.stringify(post2)}`);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, Thats exactly what i need, i will try to implement on my code but i think you got me and provide a good anwser

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can hash every object, and use a dictionary to decide whether a hash has a corresponding object. When the hash matches, you then do the real comparison. This should be able to do the job in O(n) time.

EDIT: I didn't look at the question carefully enough... The `validation` function was quite unusual, so I don't think my method works. Sorry.

Comment: But how can i do this dictionary?